# Spring MVC: How does the "view" work?

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I understanding how the `Model` and `Controller` sections of the MVC pattern and `[Spring MVC][1]` work.

However, I am not sure on the `View`.

E.g.: If I want to send data back when my `Rest end point` is hit e.g. users/{user}, if I send back a `JSP/ThymeLeaf` page or a, how does it work?

1. Is the `view` response sent by the `controller`?
2. How is `JSP` different from sending a `JSON` response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is the rendered string output. So in general you could say that there is no difference between the JSP output and JSON since both are just string responses which get interpreted by the client. But normally JSP is used for output html sites(Java Server Pages, Html rendered/generated by the server) and JSON to deliver pure data in an object structure.
The controller(in MVC general) is the middleware between model and view, so when the view gets an input the controller digest the events and manipulate the data and also when the model changes the controller triggers the gui to update.
Since the html/web world is a bit different(request->response) the Spring-MVC controller is getting the user input and triggers the rendering of the output string. So you could say the controller is delivering.
The controller is the one who changes things while the data and view are static without it.

Comment: Thanks, If i use JSP to output e,g, a html table, can I then act on the data in it? I.e. can I add javascript etc to the page in order to make it dynamic?

Comment: You can do everything as you would do with a normal HTML text. The JSP is just a template which gets filled with data on the server and delivered as a normal page when the renderer is done. So of course you can add any text you want.

Comment: Ok so it is the same essentially as a static html?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Consider a textfile on your server with a placeholder and someone request it with a text, your program fills the placeholder with that text and delivers the static text as a response. The response is always just a static text.

Comment: ok, but would I just save my JS files within my project structure in the same folder as the JSP  file?

Comment: This is up to you. The same as in static html. You can have yourJS inlined, or as a lib provided by an url, which is downloaded by the client browser when reading your html. Your JS file goes where you want it to be. Normally it should be somewhere in your project where  the jsp-files are in a folder like templates, and your static js files are in another folder like "js", the server just have to know how to access them, doesnt matter how you do it

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write about tiles and spring mvc. Mvc controller will react on your url like if you send request by localhost:8080/ myapp/classroom/hellostudent.html then spring controller will take /hellostudent.html and remove `.html` from url and match your string in `tiles.xml` file.

And about **json** so Spring mvc comes up with json api you have to use`@Responsebody` to send json object to client side.